# Creating Custom Mobile Styles in Delphi Xe7 Firemonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I was wondering if anyone knew how it would be possible to create custom styles/designs from the ground up in Delphi xe7. What I have been able to achieve is editing a former style by replacing the bitmap file containing the style and just recolouring it and saving it as a new style. That was good for the short run. That method only allows slight changes on creating new styles, I was wondering if there is a way to create something like this as a style - http://www.pixeden.com/mobile-apps/ligavit-iphone-app-ui-kit-psd. What i'm really aiming to achieve is a very appealing look. I have a designer that has strong experience in photoshop and i'm just looking for a way to adapt complex styles into Delphi xe7. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated !

Comment: Sure you can. Just copy an existing style that you think would fit best and then start applying changes to the style objects in the StyleBook.

Comment: What I'm really aiming for is something along of custom designs, so for example the Tswitch I would want the same style for ios and android, but in each respective os, the styles are different

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense. Firemonkey controls are not platform dependant. The look&Feel of a Firemonkey component is never dictated by the OS but by the style that your application is using.

Comment: Take a look at the Bitmap Style Designer (on the Tools menu). This is the tool which EMBT intend you to use for custom mobile (and indeed desktop) bitmap styles. You can take an existing mobile style (from the File drop down), use different bitmaps and change other stuff, then Save As a FireMonkey style.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I wish EMBT had more simpler tools to use, as this involves a long process of editing each image in the bitmap file.

Comment: @PeterV. if you would've tested on multiple platforms and OS versions you would know that firemonkey components are platform and even OS version dependant. The light default style looks different on Android and iOS. There is even a difference between iOS6 and iOS7.

Comment: @Remi, Embarcadero has a default style for each platform. When you switch platforms that specific style will be loaded for your Firemonkey application. If you use a custom style, one that for example you created yourself, it should look the same across all platforms.

Comment: @PeterV. Yes but still components have their own appearance. The colors may differ but not the appearance of the compontents